# watching videolectures.net on mac

Tags: macos, adobe-flash, video

How can I watch a [lecture](http://videolectures.net/mlss06tw_roweis_mlpgm/#) from videolectures.net on a Mac? I have OSX 10.12.6 and the Flip4Mac is not working/outdated (in particular, this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/player/wmcomponents.mspx) on the help [page](http://videolectures.net/site/help/) has expired. I just downloaded Chrome, so I'm not sure what's going on when I receive the following error message:

`Your browser does not support playback of available video formats. Please install Adobe Flash player or upgrade to a more modern browser.`

I also tried on Safari and Chromium after downloading Adobe Flash...

Any help would be appreciated!

Note: I originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379852/watching-videolectures-net-on-mac)

Comment: The issue is the website.  I installed flash video download tools, and it wasn't able to find a flash file to play/download.  Consider that the video is over 10+ years old...

Answer (score 1):

Tried Firefox just now and it worked

Comment: This no longer works: modern Firefox won't play Flash on Mac, either.  There seems to be contradictory information about whether this is actually Flash or Windows Media.